# Unable to get image to properly Overlay

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css

I have an image that only appears when icon located within a `pagegridview` is selected. What **should** happen is that the overlay shows, with the full sized image on top of it. What ***really*** happens is that the overlay overlays my full sized image and off centers it. My code stands as followed:

## CSS

```
#overlay{
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    background-color: #000; 
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 70) !important;
    display: none;
    z-index: 100;
}
.fullView{
    position: absolute;
}
```

## Javascript

*Works fine to display, can't test the hiding due to overlay being on top.*

```
$('.preview').click(function(){
    $("#<%=imgFull.ClientID%>").attr("src", $(this).attr('fullImg'));
    $("#overlay").show();
    $("#overlayContent").show();
});

$("#<%=imgFull.ClientID%>").click(function(){
    $("#<%=imgFull.ClientID%>").attr("src", "");
    $("#overlay").hide();
    $("#overlayContent").hide();
});
```

## Overlay/Full Image Divs

*Located right below an ASP Panel and a PageGridView*

```
<!-- Divs for displaying the full sized image. Initially hidden. Hides again when clicked -->

<div id="overlay"></div>
    <div id="overlayContent" >
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgFull" Width="400" ImageUrl="" CssClass="fullView"/>
    </div>
```

I could have sworn for the most part `position:absolute` css would solve the main portion, but the time crunch is on and I'm trying to do this with the flu. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: #overlay { position: fixed; - A fixed position element is positioned relative to the viewport, or the browser window itself. The viewport doesn't change when the window is scrolled, so a fixed positioned element will stay right where it is when the page is scrolled, try removing that and removing the position: absolute in  your .fullView and positioning it using margins and such.

Comment: @AnindyaBasu Removing both of them results in the overlay div being compressed to 0x0, and the image simply showing up between my panel and gridview. Attempting to move the fullView image via CSS has failed to do anything; it remains in its static location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was staring me in the face and I just didn't quite realize it. The `#overlay# CSS was fine, however, I needed to additionally change the`.fullView`to`fixed` as well. Once this was done, the image hovered perfectly on top of the overlay, and I was able to utilize some CSS changes in the javascript to accurately center the image.